# Move wordpress site to a real domain

Tags: bitnami

I am now  finished my word press website using BITNAMI local host. The question is how I can move this site to a real domain.
I have no programming skills.

Comment: See this: https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here.

You can deploy a Bitnami WordPress instance in any cloud provider and migrate your current data to that new server using the [All in One WordPress Migration plugin](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/how-to/migrate-wordpress/).

Once you do that, you will need to configure your domain name in the /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php file (WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME parameters). More info here: https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/wordpress/administration/configure-domain/

and generate valid SSL certificates using [the Bitnami HTTPS configuration tool](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/how-to/understand-bncert/) in case you want to secure your site

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool
```